# Need to CONCATENATE four number sets into one number set with leading zeroes intact

Tags: excel, concatenation, number-formatting

I am using Excel 2013 and need to CONCATENATE four number sets into one number set with leading zeroes intact.  I will also need to add decimal points b/t the number sets.

e.g.

```
   A      B     C     D
  111    010  00111 00011

 =CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,".",C1,".",D1)
```

My intention from the above would be to get in E1: 111.010.00111.00011

I have created custom formats for A1/B1: [$-409]000 and C1/D1: [$-409]00000.
So A1 thru D1 are displaying correctly as custom formatted numbers.
However, I have attempted many custom formats for E1 in order to get excel to display the leading zeroes with the combined data set, to no avail.

Comment: Your formula works fine for me, have you set A1:E1 as text format?

Comment: The issue is that the number in each cell, though it appears correct is actually stored without the leading zeros. so you need to put the zeros in when concatenating see @D_Bester answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format in the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"000"),".",TEXT(B1,"000"),".",TEXT(C1,"00000"),".",TEXT(D1,"00000"))
```

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds.

Comment: Thanks to all.  Ended up figuring it out and what I used was almost exactly what D_Bester has here.  Also had to add in a IF(ISBLANK) at C1 to account for some blank cells.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
 =TEXT(D1+C1*10^5+B1*10^10+A1*10^13, "000\.000\.00000\.00000")
```

[image: 000_000_00000_00000]

Comment: Not sure whether you're a mathematician or an Excel genius but either way I've learned something today. I've never seen `\.` before.

Comment: My preferred use of the `\\` as an escape character in a number format instead of quoting literals comes largely from using custom number formats in VBA and my aversion to having to deal with doubling up quotes within quoted strings.